# In C++ can abstract interfaces be used with intrusive reference counting?

Tags: c++, memory-management, interface, reference

Suppose for what ever reason in your C++ code base you have to use intrusive reference counting.
I hear and can see many advantages to classes providing their functionality though implementing multiple clean well defined interfaces. That is they should inherit from abstract classes that define the interface.

A common way of implementing intrusive reference counting is to inherit from a base class that provides the reference counting implementation. That has to be the base class so you get into diamond inheritance which starts to seem a bit overly complex. Are there better ways?

It seems trivial when not using intrusive reference counting.
Is anyone doing this combination of intrusive reference counting and inheriting multiple abstract classes?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you believe is the problem?

Comment: How is it any different for classes that provide *any other functionality*?

Comment: This is murky.  You want to bolt on an interface to a class that already uses reference counting but did not do so by implementing an interface?  That's not possible of course.

Comment: @MarcClaesen is that better?

Comment: @HansPassant So your suggesting that the reference counting part should be defined as an abstract base class that the final concrete class implements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that! There's a nice sample in the Loki template library, how to introduce such policy for [SmartPtr](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.SmartPointer) used for covering MS COM interface pointers.

Look for class `COMRefCounted` in `SmartPtr.h`.

Comment: That seems like a particularly nice example of policy based design allowing a generic smart pointer to be used with different reference counting implementations and types. I'm not sure how it answers my question though?

Comment: I'd prefer this over base class gymnastics, would be easy to use and adapt a new policy for your use case. I've done so for a similar problem already. That's why I have advised this.

Comment: But you seem to be answering how to get a generic smart pointer handle onto a intrusively reference counted object. Is there more to your answer I have not understood yet with exposing functionality though interfaces implemented by the intrusively reference counted class?